# boto3 refers FEATURE_OCSP_MODE when setting IP address, but cannot find document about it

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I got the following error message:

An HTTP Client raised and unhandled exception: name 'FEATURE_OCSP_MODE' is not defined.

However, I cannot find any reference on the internet about this FEATURE_OCSP_MODE. I was calling describe_addresses() of boto3 using Pythan 3.8. The code was working until yesterday (8/24/2020).

Comment: I'm having the same issue with python 3.6 as of today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rolled back to `boto3==1.14.46` and `snowflake-connector-python==2.2.10` as I was getting errors in both within Airflow 1.10.10 on Python 3.6.

This did the trick.

Comment: Looks like it is the issue of snowflake-connector-python, at least in my case. I set the snowflake-connector-python==2.2.10 and things are working. Thank you very much Ben!

Comment: Snowflake people shared with me that they have fixed the problem with the most recent release of snowflake-connector-python.

Answer (score 3):

I have just faced the same problem and the root cause was the snowflake-connector-python version as mentioned by Ben Campbell. In version v2.3.0 they accidentally removed the 'FEATURE_OCSP_MODE' constant but in version v2.3.1 they added it back.
The solution is to use snowflake-connector-python==2.3.1 or a newer one.

Comment: IMO this should be marked as an answer as we should be using the latest version wherever is possible. Thanks for the answer :)